# How can I decide whether a key has had .value forbidden applied?

Tags: beamer, pgfkeys

Is there a way to decide whether a given key has had the `.value forbidden` handler applied?

For example, I would like to write a handler `.only` that can be applied to keys to simulate Beamer's `\only` functionality.  A first attempt would be

```
\pgfkeys{/handlers/.only/.code args={<#1>#2}{%
  \only<#1>{\pgfkeysalso{\pgfkeyscurrentpath = {#2}}}}%
}
```

However, this fails for keys that have had `.value forbidden` applied.  Running the following produces an error because `myred={}` is effectively what happens on slide 2.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}

\pgfkeys{/handlers/.only/.code args={<#1>#2}{%
  \only<#1>{\pgfkeysalso{\pgfkeyscurrentpath = {#2}}}}%
}

\begin{document}
  \begin{frame}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[myred/.style={red}, myred/.value forbidden]
      \draw [myred/.only=<2>] (0,0) circle (1.5cm);
    \end{tikzpicture}
  \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

If there was some way to decide whether `\pgfkeyscurrentpath` has had `.value forbidden` applied, then I could use that information to send a value of `\pgfkeysnovalue`, rather than `{}`, to `\pgfkeyscurrentpath`.

Comment: Looking at the code, you can't.  The `.value forbidden` works by appending a test at the start of the key's code and no register is kept of which keys have had this added to them.  Maybe you could test `#2` and if it is empty then pass `\pgfkeysnovalue` instead of nothing.

Comment: @AndrewStacey Probably that is an answer, although one could I guess redefine `/handlers/.value forbidden/.code` to track things. (For `l3keys`, which was originally inspired by `pgfkeys`, I took a different approach and do store an explicit 'key property'.)

Comment: @AndrewStacey I thought of that, too, but for some keys you might want to pass an empty argument which would then be forced to `\pgfkeysnovalue` by mistake.  Given what you say, however, I guess it seems to be the best that one can do.

Comment: @JosephWright That's good to know about `l3keys`.  I guess that in this instance I'm forced to use `pgfkeys`.  Your suggestion of modifying `/handlers/.value forbidden/.code` is a good one, and I'll have to decide whether it is worth going that route, or whether @AndrewStacey's solution is "good enough".

Comment: I guess the question is as to how widely you want your code used.  If only by you, then you can be aware of its limitations and not do the things that break it.  If by others then you can guarantee that it will break!

Comment: @AndrewStacey If you and Joseph want to convert your comments to answers, I would be happy to accept one of them.

Comment: @JosephWright Is something like this what you meant?  `/handlers/.value forbidden/.prefix code = {\pgfkeyssetvalue{\pgfkeyscurrentpath/.@forb}{}}` and then testing whether `\pgfkeyscurrentpath/.@forb` is defined.  It seems to work great!  Thanks for the idea.  If you want to convert this to an answer, I would be happy to accept it.

Comment: Maybe you can write up an answer for this?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because solved in comments